# Which Authentication System should I select to Authenticate users in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, identity-management

I am looking for an option to securely Authenticate the users for a client-facing Web/Mobile app(hosted in Azure App Service) using Azure Active Directory, where users should be flexible enough to sign-in using either Mobile, Email, Username or even from Social Identity Providers. Moreover, we want controls in UI with all the customization. Could you please suggest me which Identity Management System should I go with?

Comment: Have a look at the MSAL library - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki

Comment: You're probably looking for something like Azure AD B2C or Auth0 etc. Or if you need something with maximal customizability then you need to build it yourself.

Comment: @juunas I have read articles for Azure AD B2C, but does it provide controls on SignIn and SIgnUp actions, can we authenticate it using our own controller?

Comment: Stack Overflow defines questions seeking recommendations as off-topic. You could try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Yes, recommendations are off-topic here :\ But yes, you could do custom validation through custom policies. But you really should do a small proof of concept first to evaluate if it is the correct tool for you as those require quite a lot of expertise to develop and manage.

Comment: @juunas can u share some links with the customizations to SignIn and SIgnUp actions using Azure ADB2C.

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario where you want to log in with flexible enough to sign-in using either Mobile, Email, Username or even from Social Identity Providers then the best and only option would be using [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview) .

Comment: I have started with Azure AD B2C and am able to customize the login page, but I need to store the username to IdentityManager by which user has logged in to the application. Can we access that anyway?

Comment: We can get users login information by using scopes open id.